# Add java requirement to eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have made a eclipse plugin and I was wondering is there any way to specify 
what version of java is needed?

My plugin only works with java 1.7 and I would like to make it so that the plugin does not install if java 1.7 is not installed.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following header to the MANIFEST.MF of your Eclipse plugin:

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

Which specifies that your plugin requires Java 1.7 in-order for your plugin to install.  From OSGi wiki:

> The Bundle-RequiredExceptionEnviornment presents a list of Execution Environments that must be present for this bundle to install.

Comment: Just to add that you can do this in the manifest/plugin.xml editor using the `Execution Environments` section on the `Overview` tab.